# Turning a cell in a UITableView on/off on the same cell, in the same view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Is it possible to make one cell in a UITableView have an ON/OFF behavior?  Basically, when I click a cell, it becomes green, which is what I want.  It doesnt go to another viewController or anything.  But then when I click that same cell again, in the same view, I want the green to disappear and for it to return back to it's previous color state.

This is how I have my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selectedPhrase = [dataTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self setCurrentPhrase:selectedPhrase];
}
```

This seems like an easy question.  I know I can drop in the `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` but that just makes it unhighlighted right away after I click it.

Thanks!

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change the background color of you `UITableViewCell` on selection, So you may use BOOL which will tell you what to fill in background (whether green or just clear color).

Access you cell through the below method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Use below  as the reference code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selectedPhrase = [dataTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self setCurrentPhrase:selectedPhrase];

      MyCutsomCell* myCell= (MyCutsomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      if(myCell.isGreen)
      {
         //Change backgroundColor to Green
      }
      else
      {
         //Clear backgroundColor
      }

      myCell.isGreen = !myCell.isGreen;
}
```

Comment: This was a good suggestion, used some of this to make it work.  Thanks!